# Cannot sort array of objects by integer value

Tags: javascript, typescript

I have an array of objects that looks something like this:

```
[
    {
        "value": 351.68474,
        "o_p": [
            "$.text"
        ]
    },
    {
        "value": 348.0095,
        "o_p": [
            "$.text"
        ]
    },
    {
        "value": 365.2453,
        "o_p": [
            "$.text"
        ]
    }
]
```

I want to try to sort this object based on `value` and to do so, I have tried this:

```
const sorted_object = orig_object.sort((a, b) => a.value - b.value);
```

I found the above sorting strategy when looking at other answers on this site.

However, I get this error and I can't seem to figure it out:

```
ERROR TypeError: Cannot assign to read only property '0' of object '[object Array]'
```

Is there something obvious that I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [`Array.prototype.sort`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort) method mutates the array. Based on the error, you seem to be dealing with a read-only array for some reason, hence the error when using the mutating `.sort`.

If a clone is fine, you can use `[ ...array ].sort(...)` to "clone-and-sort".